# Aligning 4 divs side by side with percentage dimensions in a parent div

Tags: html, css, alignment

how can I achieve this?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="inset">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
        <div class="uncollapse">
        </div>
        <div class="featuredbox">
        <div class="rank"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="desc"></div>
        <div class="votes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.featuredbox {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.featuredbox .rank {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.featuredbox .banner {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .desc {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .votes {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[What it should look like http://puu.sh/49szH.png](http://puu.sh/49szH.png)

How can I do to make them align in the particular format without using fixed values?

Thank you!

It's asking me to put more details, but I don't have any more to give :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put this css for you html

```
.featuredbox {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.featuredbox div{
    float:left;
}
.featuredbox .rank {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.featuredbox .banner {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .desc {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .votes {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    top:-50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed HTML code a bit. Created three main divs (left, middile one with two child and right)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="inset">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
        <div class="uncollapse">
        </div>
        <div class="featuredbox">
        <div class="rank">Rank</div>
         <div class="middileDiv">
        <div class="banner">Banner</div>
        <div class="desc">Desc</div>
             </div>
        <div class="votes">Votes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
@charset "utf-8";

.featuredbox {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #d8d8d8;
}

.featuredbox .rank {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

.featuredbox .banner {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .desc {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}

.featuredbox .votes {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

.middileDiv {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/RvAwB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few problems that you are looking at here.

First, I would remove the height: 160px rule.

Next, you need to realize that by adding a border to the featured box, you are adding 2px to the width of the box. So unless you are using box-sizing: border-box in your CSS, you are basicay saying that the featured box is 100% wide plus 2px.

Then, you need to float: left each of the boxes inside the featured box. Again, remove the heights from these boxes.

You'll find that by adding height to boxes that are filled with content that you don't know how much space it will take up, you might chop content off the bottom if it is too long. Removing the height will allow the boxes to grow in height in response to the content they contain.

Finally, you will need to clear the float on the featured box. There are a few ways to do this, but the latest way to do it is:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Also, you should read up more on how to position boxes using floats, because for now (until flexbox is ready to use), this is the best way to do it.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/